# Yii2 Gridview column summary based on calculated child value

Tags: gridview, yii2

I'm trying to calculate a column summary in `GridView` based upon calculated child values. How can this be achieved?

In view:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'showFooter' => true,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'header' => 'Any header',
                'value' => function ($model){return $model->sumChildvalue();},
                'footer' => 'VALUE SHOULD BE CALCULATED HERE...',

            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

I believe I could run a function in Model, re-calculating the `sumChildvalue()` for every model in `$dataProvider`, but that seems non-efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the value from outside, it can be calculated before starting the GridView::widget, so you can iterate over $dataProvider->models before.

```
<?php
$footerValue = 0;
foreach ($dataProvider->models as $model) {
    $footerValue += $model->value;
}
?>

<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'showFooter' => true,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'header' => 'Any header',
                'value' => function ($model){
                      return $model->sumChildvalue();
                 },
                'footer' => $footerValue, // Pass the value here

            ],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```